# Mysql Query speed takes 50 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below Query which takes around 50 seconds to run, is there a way to make it faster? i have not done any indexing yet and will try to do that in the near future but i am still new in this. the problem is not using indexing.

```
   Select stock.StockID As StockID,
  stock.BinLocation As BinLocation,
  stock.StockCode As StockCode,
  stock.Descr As Descr,
  stock.Currency As Currency,
  stock.Notes As Notes,
  stocklocations.Quantity As Quantity,
  stocklocations.SLNID As SLNID,
  stock.ConditionA As ConditionA,
  stocklocationsname.SLN As SLN,
  stock.DateAdded As DateAdded,
  (Case When (stock.Currency = 'Euro') Then (1.05 * stock.unitprice)
    When (stock.Currency = 'GBP') Then (1.24 * stock.unitprice)
    When (stock.Currency = 'USD') Then (1 * stock.unitprice) End) As unitprice,
  stock.DepName As DepName,
  stockhistory.POID As POID,
  stock.POID As POID1,
  stock.PartNumber As PartNumber,
  vender.VendorName As VendorName,
  equiptype.EQName As EQName,
  groupname.Name As Name
From ((((((stock
  Join stocklocations On stock.StockID = stocklocations.StockID)
  Join stocklocationsname On stocklocations.SLNID = stocklocationsname.SLNID)
  Left Join stockhistory On stockhistory.SHID = (Select Min(stockhistory.SHID)
    From stockhistory Where stockhistory.StockID = stock.StockID))
  Left Join po On stockhistory.POID = po.POID)
  Left Join vender On po.Vender = vender.VendorID)
  Left Join equiptype On stock.EquipType = equiptype.EquipTypeID)
  Left Join groupname On stock.GroupNameID = groupname.GroupNameID
Where stocklocations.Quantity > 0 And stock.Status <> 'obsolete'
```

Comment: And how does your schema look? What indexes do you have defined?

Comment: As a minimum, questions about query performance ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN. That said, my guess is that the correlated subquery is what's causing the bottleneck.

Comment: I still can't see the EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have an index on `stockhistory.StockID`:

```
ALTER TABLE stockhistory ADD INDEX (StockID);
```

That should speed up the subqueries on `stockhistory`. Alternatively, since you're retrieving the minimum value of `SHID`, you might include that column in the index as well:

```
ALTER TABLE stockhistory ADD INDEX (StockID, SHID);
```

Adding indexes does not create any restrictions or logical constraints (with the exception of unique indexes). However, as stated in [8.3 Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html) from the MySQL documentation:

> Although it can be tempting to create an indexes for every possible column used in a query, unnecessary indexes waste space and waste time for MySQL to determine which indexes to use. Indexes also add to the cost of inserts, updates, and deletes because each index must be updated. You must find the right balance to achieve fast queries using the optimal set of indexes.

Figuring out which indexes to create is something of an art. A good start is to investigate query execution with `EXPLAIN`, as described in [8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: thanks mate, this actually reduced the entire time to 0.9 seconds and i only did the first indexing. i am not very familiar with indexes but i need to learn more about it. dose it create any restrictions?

Comment: I added some more details about indexes to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1 ) Remove unuseful ()  and avoid nested  left join

2 )   don't use where fo column involved in left join because this way became inner  join

3 ) instead of a subselect try using a join  of for the min value related  to stockid in stockhistory

```
  Select 
    stock.StockID As StockID,
    stock.BinLocation As BinLocation,
    stock.StockCode As StockCode,
    stock.Descr As Descr,
    stock.Currency As Currency,
    stock.Notes As Notes,
    stocklocations.Quantity As Quantity,
    stocklocations.SLNID As SLNID,
    stock.ConditionA As ConditionA,
    stocklocationsname.SLN As SLN,
    stock.DateAdded As DateAdded,
    Case When stock.Currency = 'Euro' Then 1.05 * stock.unitprice
          When stock.Currency = 'GBP' Then 1.24 * stock.unitprice
          When stock.Currency = 'USD' Then 1 * stock.unitprice End As unitprice,
  stock.DepName As DepName,
  stockhistory.POID As POID,
  stock.POID As POID1,
  stock.PartNumber As PartNumber,
  vender.VendorName As VendorName,
  equiptype.EQName As EQName,
  groupname.Name As Name
From  stock
  Join stocklocations On stock.StockID = stocklocations.StockID 
        and stocklocations.Quantity > 0 
            And stock.Status <> 'obsolete'
  Join stocklocationsname On stocklocations.SLNID = stocklocationsname.SLNID
  Left Join ( 
      Select stockhistory.StockID, Min(stockhistory.SHID)
      From stockhistory 
      group by stockhistory.StockID )  t_h on t_h StockID = stockhistory.StockID
  Left Join po On stockhistory.POID = po.POID
  Left Join vender On po.Vender = vender.VendorID
  Left Join equiptype On stock.EquipType = equiptype.EquipTypeID
  Left Join groupname On stock.GroupNameID = groupname.GroupNameID
```

be sure you have also proper index on the tables and columns involved  in join

Comment: it dose not work , can you explain what is t_h on t_n StockID = stockhistory.StockID ?

Comment: answer  updated  with  t_h  on t_h StockID  ... t_h  is  the name for  a select table use for buil a join instead of serveral subselect  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try without brackets which you write along joins and FROM.

```
Select stock.StockID As StockID,
stock.BinLocation As BinLocation,
stock.StockCode As StockCode,
stock.Descr As Descr,
stock.Currency As Currency,
stock.Notes As Notes,
stocklocations.Quantity As Quantity,
stocklocations.SLNID As SLNID,
stock.ConditionA As ConditionA,
stocklocationsname.SLN As SLN,
stock.DateAdded As DateAdded,
(Case When (stock.Currency = 'Euro') Then (1.05 * stock.unitprice)
  When (stock.Currency = 'GBP') Then (1.24 * stock.unitprice)
  When (stock.Currency = 'USD') Then (1 * stock.unitprice) End) As unitprice,
stock.DepName As DepName,
stockhistory.POID As POID,
stock.POID As POID1,
stock.PartNumber As PartNumber,
vender.VendorName As VendorName,
equiptype.EQName As EQName,
groupname.Name As Name
From stock
Join stocklocations On stock.StockID = stocklocations.StockID
Join stocklocationsname On stocklocations.SLNID = stocklocationsname.SLNID
Left Join stockhistory On stockhistory.SHID = (Select Min(stockhistory.SHID) From stockhistory Where stockhistory.StockID = stock.StockID)
Left Join po On stockhistory.POID = po.POID
Left Join vender On po.Vender = vender.VendorID
Left Join equiptype On stock.EquipType = equiptype.EquipTypeID
Left Join groupname On stock.GroupNameID = groupname.GroupNameID
Where stocklocations.Quantity > 0 And stock.Status <> 'obsolete'
```

Comment: OK You can vote up :) 
By the way, 1st issue was that brackets. 2nd issue is too much joins. but if its necessary then you need to create indexes

Answer (score 0):

how much time it takes to execute without this?

```
Left Join stockhistory On stockhistory.SHID = (Select Min(stockhistory.SHID)
    From stockhistory Where stockhistory.StockID = stock.StockID))
```

If it takes 5-6 secs, then you should convert this min SHID group by StockID to a view, and join with the view first, then stockhistory itself to get the stockhistory.POID